# How do I remove the filter from my VS 2022 Connected Services dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I few days ago when I was adding a new connected service (MS Identity) there was a listbox shown asking me if I wanted to continue using some of the Tenants. I did not want to continue using the ones listed so I unchecked them. However, I've added new Tenants in Azure and they don't appear in the list and now my login is shown as filtered and I don't know how to remove the filter:

Connected Service Dialog:

[image]

I wanted all my Tenants to appear in the dropdown.